# How to change the contents of a block dynamically on django?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

**SEE FIXED CODE BELOW**

I'm working on my first web page project using django  1.8. My web page has a section that consists of a product menu and a column displaying a different view based on selected menu item.

At first I tried an approach where each of the menu buttons have a onclick  js function assigned that changes the contents of the block. I was thinking that I would then write the html code of each product into separate file where it would be read by the js function. I got it partially working but it feels kinda sketchy.

My second approach was based on using django templates but I run into some errors as a beginner I couldn't quite figure out what exactly is the problem. I would highly appreciate if someone could pinpoint what I'm doing wrong or tell me what's the right approach for changing the contents dynamically.

The errors I'm getting currently:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/productmonitor/
NoReverseMatch at /productmonitor/
Reverse for 'product' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'productmonitor/(?P<product_name>[a-z]+)/$']

http://127.0.0.1:8000/productmonitor/
NoReverseMatch at /productmonitor/dualpol/
Reverse for 'product' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'productmonitor/(?P<product_name>[a-z]+)/$']
```

urls.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<product_name>[A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)/$', views.product, name='product'),
    url(r'^information/$', views.information, name='information'),
    url(r'^casedatabase/$', views.casedatabase, name='casedatabase'),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.views import generic
# Create your views here.
from .models import Product

def index(request, product_name='default'):
    #template = 'productmonitor/index.html'
    if product_name == 'dualpol':
        template = 'productmonitor/base_productmonitor_dualpol.html'
    if product_name == 'rhi':
        template = 'productmonitor/base_productmonitor_rhi.html'

    template = 'productmonitor/base_productmonitor.html'
    test_context = {
                    'products' : Product.objects.all(),                   
                    }
    return render(request, template, test_context)

def product(request, product_name='dualpol'):
    if product_name == 'dualpol':
        template = 'productmonitor/base_productmonitor_dualpol.html'
    if product_name == 'rhi':
        template = 'productmonitor/base_productmonitor_rhi.html'

    test_context = {
                    'products' : Product.objects.all(),                   
                    }
    return render(request, template, test_context)
```

base_productmonitor.html

```
{% extends "productmonitor/base.html" %}    
{% block content %}
    <div class="productSelectMenu">
        <ul>
            <p>Test</p>
            {% for product in products %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'productmonitor:product' 'dualpol' %}">{{ product.name }}<a/></li>  
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>

    {% block productcontent %}
        <div id="productView" class="productView">
            <p>Default productView content</p>    
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

base_productmonitor_dualpol.html

```
{% extends "productmonitor/base_productmonitor.html" %}
{% block productcontent %}
<p>
    dualpol
</p>
{% endblock %}
```

**EDIT: FIXED VERSION**

urls.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^product/(?P<product_name>[a-z]+)/$', views.product, name='product'),
    url(r'^information/$', views.information, name='information'),
    url(r'^casedatabase/$', views.casedatabase, name='casedatabase'),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
]
```

views.py

```
enter code here
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, redirect
from django.views import generic
# Create your views here.
from .models import Product

def index(request, product_name=''):
    return redirect('productmonitor:product', product_name='dualpol')

def product(request, product_name):
    if product_name == 'dualpol':
        template = 'productmonitor/base_productmonitor_dualpol.html'
    if product_name == 'rhi':
        template = 'productmonitor/base_productmonitor_rhi.html'

    test_context = {
                    'products' : Product.objects.all(),                   
                    }
    return render(request, template, test_context)

def information(request):
    template = 'productmonitor/base_information.html'
    context = {}
    return render(request, template, context)

def casedatabase(request):
    template = 'productmonitor/base_case-database.html'
    context = {}
    return render(request, template, context)

def contact(request):
    template = 'productmonitor/base_contact.html'
    context = {}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

base_productmonitor.html

```
{% extends "productmonitor/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="productSelectMenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="{% url 'productmonitor:product' 'dualpol' %}">Dual pol<a/></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'productmonitor:product' 'rhi' %}">Rhi<a/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    {% block productcontent %}
        <div id="productView" class="productView">
            <p>Default productView content</p>    
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

base_productmonitor_dualpol.html

```
{% extends "productmonitor/base_productmonitor.html" %}
{% block productcontent %}
<div id="productView" class="productView">
    <p>
        dualpol
    </p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Have you defined `productmonitor` as namespace for the included urls?

Comment: Yes I have: url(r'^productmonitor/', include('productmonitor.urls', namespace='productmonitor'))

Comment: Please check the kwargs you're passing matches the url regex pattern. I see that the regex in error is different from the one in `urls.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what the error is saying that the render in your product function is not getting the right `<product_name>` to use. It's showing that the arguments that it has (the `<product_name>` that it is trying) are none. So what you have to do in your product function is to try and make sure that you are really getting a `<product_name>`.

Comment: Thanks, it took me a while to find the error but it was indeed related to the kwargs not passed on correctly to the view. I added the fixed version of the code to the question, not sure if I should have also removed the old one.

Comment: @MrBronson sorry if my answer post was a bit confusing, I forgot to rap the `<product_name>` with a code block. Glad I could help!